# EM wave generation from different frames of reference

Tags: electromagnetism, equivalence-principle

Take 2 observers and a charged particle,

Observer S is stationary to the particle and sees the electric field and no magnetic field as he is stationary to the particle.

Observer A decides to accelerate and decelerate over and over back and forth in front of the particle.

From A's frame of reference, it can be said, by the equivalence principal, that the particle is accelerating and decelerating in A's frame of reference and therefor should emit a EM wave.

So A sees a Em wave come off the particle.

But wait, S does not see any such thing, other than A moving back and forth...

What am I missing??
Thanks!
Eric

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing (and hoping) that you understand that both these observers cannot be in a freefall (aka inertial, or Lorentz) frame at the same time. That is, if observer $S$ is in a freefall frame, then $A$ will measure his/her own proper acceleration with an accelerometer. So you can see that you can't apply, say, the Lamor formula (or its relativistic generalization the Liénard–Wiechert potentials) to the charge's motion as seen by $A$ and deduce there is radiation.

However, there is a simpler version of a question very like yours which, to my knowledge, has not been fully resolved.

Simply drop an electron onto the surface of the Earth and let it sit there. Its proper acceleration is $g$, so, by the equivalence principle, **it should radiate**. I'm not expert with the current state of contemplation of this problem, so we probably need another answer to complete the answer to your question. But what I can say is that the power we'd expect to see radiated from charge sitting on the Earth's surface is fantastically small. From the Lamor formula:

$$P=\frac{q^2\,a^2}{6\,\pi\,\epsilon_0\,c^3}$$

I make the radiation from an electron in this situation to be $5.5\times10^{-52}{\rm watts}$. To put this into more meaningful units, this is $7\times 10^{-39}$ of the electron's rest mass per second. That is, it would take $3\times10^{20}$ ages of the universe to radiate the equivalent of its own rest mass. So we wouldn't expect to be able to measure this effect on Earth even though, as far as I can reason, it should be real. Owing to its miniscule size, it would have to be checked by astronomical measurements of radiation from much higher gravity phenomena.

---

It seems the wording above is causing some confusion, best illustrated by AnnaV's question:

> An electron is an elementary particle and cannot lose part of its mass. Anyway why would it radiate its own mass, and not of the earth's gravitational field which is supply in the $g$? similar to Hawking radiation?

Sorry for the bad wording: I'm not saying it's radiating its own mass, I'm *comparing* the radiation rate to its own mass, just to try to give some meaning to the figures. Otherwise, $5\times 10^{-52}{\rm watts}$ is a bit meaningless. As you say, you can interpret the radiation energy as being similar to Hawking radiation (Unruh radiation) and coming from the gravitational field.

Comment: An electron is an elementary particle and cannot lose part of its mass. Anyway why would it radiate its own mass, and not of the earth's gravitational field which is supplyin the g?  similar to Hawking radiation?

Comment: @annav Sorry for the bad wording: I'm not saying it's radiating its own mass, I'm *comparing* the radiation rate to its own mass, just to try to give some meaning to the figures. Otherwise, $5\times 10^{-52}{\rm watts}$ is a bit meaningless. As you say, you can interpret the radiation energy as being similar to Hawking radiation (Unruh radiation) and coming from the gravitational field.

Comment: I want to underline some misunderstanding. The statement "Observer S is stationary to the particle and sees the electric field and no magnetic field ..." is not right. The electron has a magnetic dipole moment and by the same way, as one could measure the electric field by a test charge, the electron's magnetic field could be measured by a magnet. So the electron has a magnetic field.

Comment: I think your description of an electron on the surface of Earth is close to my question.  I didn't mean to suggest there was NO magnetic field, indeed I never mention what type of particle it was, simply a 'charged' particle...so strike that bit.  I simply wanted to point out that it seemed like it might be possible to create two different frames of reference, where one would see a EM wave emitted, and one would not.

Comment: @user2016641 I agree that the magnetic field is unimportant to your question. The point is that one can only apply things like the Lamor formula to a freefall frame. General Relativity really does tell the difference between your two frames. Whilst it is of course true that the Einstein field equations equally apply to both frames (they are related by a smooth co-ordinate transformation), only one of them can be a Lorentz frame (all of its points follow geodesics). Physically, in frame S, your accelerometer would read nought; in frame A, it would be detecting oscillatory motion. The question..

Comment: @user2016641 ..of which is accelerating can be unambiguously answered using accelerometers. It's a common misconception that relativity means everything is relative: acceleration in the sense just described (measurement by accelerometer) is absolute. It is "relative" in the sense that the Einstein field equations apply and the calculation of curvature can be done equally well in either frame. So no, there would be an unambiguous answer, agreed on by both observers, as to whether or not the charge radiates.