# Will stationary charge radiate E.M waves if observer is accelerating?

Tags: special-relativity, electromagnetic-radiation, reference-frames, inertial-frames, observers

For ex. if my frame of reference is oscillating then will i see E.M waves produced from a charge which is not oscillating with any other or ground frame of reference?  Can i get a really clear answer ...like yes or no and why ?

Comment: Not just that, [even the vacuum can look non-empty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unruh_effect) when seen from an accelerating frame.

Comment: I won't dupehammer this, but I think it is a duplicate of [Will a change in reference frame produce light?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/305501/will-a-change-in-reference-frame-produce-light) and also [EM wave generation from different frames of reference](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/214431/em-wave-generation-from-different-frames-of-reference).

Answer (score 2):

No, it won't.  Electromagnetic waves are produced by charged particles undergoing [proper acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_acceleration), which would be measurable by an accelerometer attached to the particle.

In your scenario, the particle is not undergoing proper acceleration.  Its apparent motion is caused by the "acceleration" of your coordinates, and would not register on the particle's accelerometer.

In relativity theory, velocity is relative but (proper) acceleration is unambiguous, and this is what determines whether a charge will radiate or not.

Comment: What if a charge is accelerating and  frame of reference is also accelerating with it so that charge seems to be at rest ...and there are no other framea such as ground

Comment: If the accelerometer attached to the particle registers a nonzero acceleration, then it will radiate.  If it registers no acceleration, then it will not.  I don't know what you mean by "there are no other frames."

Comment: Ii mean to say that the accelerometer which you are attaching measures  acceleration of charge with respect to which frame ??

Comment: if there are only two things an accelerating charge and acceleraring me snycronisingly ...and rest is vaccum i.e no plant no ground ...as there is nothing like universal frame of reference

Comment: You're thinking of coordinate acceleration.  Proper acceleration can be *felt* - it has physically measurable effects, and is not frame dependent.

Comment: There is no universal frame of reference, but there are always *inertial* frames.  You can tell whether you're in an accelerating frame or not.

Comment: Its looks like i got the answer ......that means if both charge and me are accelerating at same rate i will detect E.M waves as i can feel that i am accelerating as both becomes non inertial frame ....thanx alot and plzz correct me if i even got anything wrong