# Regarding accelerated charges produce electromagnetic waves

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, acceleration, charge

I know that accelerating charges produce electromagnetic waves. I do not however understand the main reasoning behind this. Most of my knowledge of this topic is from internet sources and stack exchange answers. Based on my limited exposure to the theory and knowledge of Maxwell equations, I have a doubt.

If electromagnetic waves are produced by accelerating charges, then **will I observe EM waves if I accelerate with respect to stationary charge?** For eg.- if I am doing SHM at a distance from a charged particle in a direction perpendicular to the distance vector or something like that.

P.S.- I am a Grade 12 student and do not know much about Relativity or Quantum theory.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will stationary charge radiate E.M waves if observer is accelerating?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/355401/will-stationary-charge-radiate-e-m-waves-if-observer-is-accelerating)